# Riak - partitions waiting to handoff

Tags: riak, riak-kv

I'm running a cluster with 24 nodes with 1024 partitions
riak_kv_version : <<"2.1.7-226">>

I have 142 partitions waiting to handoff for more than 10 days. There's no ongoing transfer in the cluster.
Under this node riak@0037-internal.xx.com, I can see this error message

`<0.30120.441>@riak_core_handoff_sender:start_fold:282 hinted transfer of riak_kv_vnode from 'riak@0037-internal.xx.com' 994791641816054037097625320706298110058774396928 to 'riak@0029-internal.xx.com' 994791641816054037097625320706298110058774396928 failed because of error:{badmatch,{error,closed}} [{riak_core_handoff_sender,start_fold,5,[{file,"src/riak_core_handoff_sender.erl"},{line,132}]}] <0.9143.441>@riak_core_handoff_sender:start_fold:282 hinted transfer of riak_kv_vnode from 'riak@0037-internal.xx.com' 616571003248974668617179538802181898917346541568 to 'riak@0035-internal.xx.com' 616571003248974668617179538802181898917346541568 failed because of error:{badmatch,{error,closed}} [{riak_core_handoff_sender,start_fold,5,[{file,"src/riak_core_handoff_sender.erl"},{line,132}]}]`

When I check the partitions list (riak-admin cluster partitions) I notice that all partitions which are waiting for handoff are marked as secondary. I was expecting all those partitions type to be primary

Any  idea about how to fix this issue?

I have remove for example a node where there are partitions waiting for handoff from the ring, and put it back to the ring. Still seeing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `riak-admin ring-status`? If `ring-ready` is *false* then something is wrong e.g. a node is part way through leaving or joining. Check `riak-admin cluster status` to find this out. If any nodes in there show `!down` then mark them down with `riak-admin down <nodename>` and `riak-admin ring-status` should then switch `ring-ready` to *true*. You may also wish to double check that transfers are allowed i.e. your transfer limit is not set to 0 by running `riak-admin transfer-limit`. If it is set to 0, you can update it with `riak-admin transfer-limit 2` to return it to the default setting. The maximum possible value is 8.

The Riak KV installable package is a collection of components with different versions. The package Riak KV 2.1.7 does not exist, but there is an internal component called riak_kv with version `<<"2.1.7-226">>`. To help better, I need to know the installed version of Riak KV (which then tells us the versions of all components) and not just the version of one component. Please determine your Riak KV version by running `riak version` for KV 2.x and earlier or `riak versions` for KV 3.x and higher.

For people using Riak KV 3.x who refer to this question later, please substitute `riak-admin` in any commands for `riak admin`.

Comment: Here's the output of riak-admin ring-status. ================================== Claimant ===================================
Claimant:  'media-riak@internal.xxx.com'
Status:     up
Ring Ready: true

============================== Ownership Handoff ==============================
No pending changes.

============================== Unreachable Nodes ==============================
All nodes are up and reachable

Comment: I have constantly this error in riak logs
[error] <0.306.0>@riak_core_ring:check_tainted:263 Error: riak_core_gossip/send_ring_to :: Sending tainted ring over gossip
[error] <0.175.0>@riak_core_ring:check_tainted:263 Error: riak_core_ring/reconcile :: reconciling tainted external ring
[error] <0.175.0>@riak_core_ring:check_tainted:263 Error: riak_core_ring/reconcile :: reconciling tainted internal ring

Comment: Although we're operating with very limited information, you might like to try executing the following from a `riak attach` session.

```
riak_core_ring_manager:ring_trans(fun(Ring, _) ->
   Ring2 = riak_core_ring:update_meta(riak_core_ring_tainted, false, Ring),
   {new_ring, Ring2}
end, ok), ok.
```

However, we cannot guarantee this will work as we do not have sufficient data to work with. As always, be sure to test this in a safe environment before applying to production.